# Issues with bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css

The code is right, but my slide button is not working,

Here is my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Testimonials -->
<section id="testimonials">

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it so it is a [mcve] - you can get images from placeholder.com and you need to describe what "does not work" mean - it seems to work just fine now I added jQuery and bootstrab libraries. I cannot SEE the buttons but they work

Comment: Agreed, according to the snippet your carousel is working fine. Also, I hope you are enjoying Angela's course.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks I have  edited some of my code and now it runs successfully...one of my links is missing

Comment: @Mamdlv thank you and  ya I am enjoying it